# UICollectionViewCell is being selected multiple times when scrolling down?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a custom UIView checkmark icon that shows up when the user taps a particular subclassed UICollectionViewCell. However, when I scroll the icon appears on multiple cells without the user actually tapping on those cells. From what I researched so far, it appears this is caused from the cell reuse.

What would be some good solutions to fix this issue?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Good thing to do would be to create a property in your subclassed cell as `isSelected`. And then in the item creation method put a check

```
if (item.isSelected) {
    //show checkmark
} else {
    //remove checkmark
}
```

This way is the item does not have the iSelected Property set as true, the extra checkboxes will not come.